# Is it possible to import Javascript functions in emcc compiled wasm code?

Tags: emscripten, webassembly

I read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Using_the_JavaScript_API and http://webassembly.org/docs/js/, and it seems all examples I've found for calling Javascript functions from wasm are written in the LISP-inspired syntax.

Is it possible to import JS functions in wasm using emscripten C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Emscripten [documents how to do this](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html). The easiest thing is to declare the JS function as `extern "C"` in C++. It'll be in your wasm module's exports, which you then need to pass in as an import.

As another example, the [wasm waterfall](https://github.com/WebAssembly/waterfall/blob/master/src/build.py#L1014) build [musl](https://github.com/jfbastien/musl/tree/wasm-prototype-1/arch/wasm32) in JavaScript, and runs some [GCC tests](https://github.com/WebAssembly/waterfall/blob/master/src/build.py#L1084) which it compiles to wasm. All C library functions are in JS, and wasm calls into JS for them. No magic: the C library functions are just declared as `extern "C"` and then passed in as [an import](https://github.com/jfbastien/musl/blob/wasm-prototype-1/arch/wasm32/wasm.js#L817).

Comment: Please use commit IDs to create permanent links when referring to code in Github. Your Github links are already ruined. Here's a commit-id-based link to the relevant test demonstrating the `--js-library` flag https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/6b8afa59354ec165e6be966c8e891170c4e3c5bd/tests/test_core.py#L5043